# xcode6 (swift)- Build archive is fail

Tags: xcode, archive

I have a problem. I've written a project with swift. Project is working, not error. But when I'm archiving for send to apple, the project have read errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (my project have avfoundation.framework)
Errors:

1- CoreAudioKit/CoreAudioTypes.h file not found

2- AudioToolbox/AudioFormat.h file not found

3- Could not build Objective-c module AVFoundation